# Slow parallelized loop in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a simple for loop in Python following the instructions that I have found on internet.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

n = 100000
k = 3
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def processInput(i):
    return i**2

#This should be the parallelized loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(processInput)(i) for i in range(n))
    print("Time parallelized loop:")
    print(time.time()-start)
```

The time required to run this script is the following:

```
Time parallelized loop:
5.14900016785
```

The very strange fact is that if I run a sequential loop, the time is much smaller. This is the sequential loop:

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

n = 100000
k = 3
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def processInput(i):
    return i**2

#This should be the squential loop
start = time.time()
results = [processInput(i) for i in range(n)]
print("Time Sequential loop:")
print(time.time() - start)
```

I get this time:

```
Time Sequential loop:
0.107000112534
```

At this point it is clear that I am missing something. How is it possible that the sequential loop is so faster than the parallelized one?

Comment: At a guess, I'd suspect you were paying that much time in overhead for creating 100000 delayed objects, etc. Try hoisting the `delayed(processInput)` out of the loop, and see if that affects your time: `cache_delayed = delayed(processInput); results = Para..(cache_delayed(i) for i in range...`

Comment: Better, but still slow:
 
3.13700008392 seconds

Comment: The Parallel docs mention a `batch_size=[auto]` parameter that can also be an integer. Maybe try with batch_size=1000?

Comment: There is some overhead in communicating between the subprocesses that Parallel spawns to perform the task. Since the task is just squaring a single number, the overhead is much more than the actual work done. Try making processInput also do n iterations of arithmetic and you'll see the difference.